# alert is not working in windows phonegap

Tags: cordova, cross-platform, windows-phone

I am trying to port the android phonegap application  to windows phone.

I have searched  and many of them  telling  navigator.notification.alert("message");

instead of alert("message") .But for me , both of them seems to be not working. One more thing I am using jquery. I am able to see same page perfectly , what I had seen in my android emulator.  But this click event and alert is not seems to be working . Please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

I have used below mentioned to sdk to develop the app.

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Version WPDTRTMRel - 40219.209 Microsoft
>   .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319 SP1Rel
>
> Installed Version: PD Express
>
> Microsoft Visual Basic 2010   02053-169-2504541-70001 Microsoft Visual
>   Basic 2010
>
> Microsoft Visual C# 2010   02053-169-2504541-70001 Microsoft Visual C#
>   2010
>
> Microsoft Windows Phone 7.1 Profiler   02053-169-2504541-70001
>   Microsoft Windows Phone 7.1 Profiler
>
> Windows Phone SDK 7.1 - ENU   02053-169-2504541-70001 Windows Phone
>   SDK 7.1 - ENU
>
> Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone   5.2.819.0 Microsoft
>   Advertising SDK for Windows Phone Build 5.2.819.0
>
> Microsoft XNA Game Studio   4.0 Microsoft XNA Game Studio 4.0 Build
>   4.0.30901.0

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm not exactly solving your problem, but i recommend a replacement for the native ugly "alert".

SimpleDialog2:
http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2

Answer (score 0):

you will to ensure:

- Notification.cs is present in rootProject/Plugins/ ?
- features Notification is present in config.xml  ?